# convert class file into function (hooks)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this class made in pure react and I would like to convert it into react hooks. I started to start but it didn't go as expected. Here are the codes:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { name: 'Frarthur' };
    
    this.changeName = this.changeName.bind(this);
  }
  
  changeName(newName) {
    this.setState({
      name: newName
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <Child name={this.state.name} onChange={this.changeName} />
  }
}
);
```

I would like this example made in react hooks.

```
function Parent () {
  const [changeName] = React.useState(name);
  const handleIncrement = () => setChange(newName);

return (
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>{name}</div>
      <Parent name={this.state.name} onChange={this.changeName} />
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
```

Comment: I suggest going through https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Hook analog your `Parent` class component:

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [name, changeName] = React.useState('Frarthur');

    return <Child name={name} onChange={changeName} />;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If In undestood well your need, your want to convert it into a **functional component** Not **HOOK**

```
const Parent = (props) => {
    const [name, setName] = React.useState("Frathur");

    const changeName = (newName) => {
        setName(newName);
    }

    return <Child name={name} onChange={changeName} />
}
```